# How do I use .ToUpper or .ToLower on a certain word in a big sentence?

Tags: c#

```
string testSentence = "this is a test sentence and I WANT TO SEE HOW IT WILL LOOK LIKE hoping this part is big";

        int firstLetter = testSentence.IndexOf("this");
        int length = "this is a test sentence and".Length;
        string upperSentence = testSentence.Substring(firstLetter, length).ToUpper();

        int secondLetter = testSentence.IndexOf(" I");
        int length2 = " I WANT TO SEE HOW IT WILL LOOK LIKE".Length;
        string lowerSentence = testSentence.Substring(secondLetter, length2).ToLower();

        int thirdSentence = testSentence.IndexOf(" hoping");
        int length1 = " hoping this part is big".Length;
        string get = testSentence.Substring(thirdSentence, length1).ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine(upperSentence + lowerSentence + get);
```

Can somebody please tell me how would you capitalize in all big or small letters only one word in the middle of the sentence? For example, make the word ''LOOK'' in small case letters. Does the ''.Length'' call has to be used or is there a different way than literally typing the word or part of the sentence that I want to convert to upper or lower cases?

The problem I have with this is, I cannot isolate just one word and make it low/big letters because then the rest of the string after the particular word is also in the lower/upper cases

Comment: `s = s.Replace(word, word.ToUpper());`?

Comment: Do you need to account for partial matches? Suppose the word is "right". Do you need to distinguish that from "fright" "rightly", "right-handed", and "far-right?"

Comment: @ScottHannen that is a good question. Im learning through Codecademy and after every lesson I just have more questions than answers

Comment: @AllAboutProgramming Try thinking about logic first. Forget it's programming. What would you do if you were asked to do that. List the steps you would do as a human being then keep separating the step into smaller steps until they make sense for code to replicate.

Comment: One approach is to document several inputs, and what the expected output would be. You can post them with your question because it makes your intent clearer. And the best part is that you can use them to write unit tests so you'll easily know when your code works.

Answer (score -1):

In line with @Franck's advice, think about the problem as a human.  You have three things:

- a sentence
- words that you want to be big
- words that you want to be small

The sentence can really be broken down into a collection of words (ignoring punctuation).  You want to go through the collection of words and change some of them to be uppercase and some of them to be lowercase - all the rest of the words you want to leave as they are.

Here is some code that does this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // modify these as you please
        string testSentence = "this is a test sentence and I WANT TO SEE HOW IT WILL LOOK LIKE hoping this part is big";
        string[] wordsToUpperCase = new string[] { "hoping", "test" };
        string[] wordsToLowerCase = new string[] { "look", "is" };
        
        // start processing
        // split the sentence into words        
        string[] wordsInSentence = testSentence.Split(' ');
        
        // a List to hold the reworked words
        var outputWords = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        
        // process the words
        foreach (string currentWord in wordsInSentence)
        {
            // check the wordsToUpperCase array for the current word
            bool shouldUpperCaseThisWord = wordsToUpperCase.Any(stringToTest => stringToTest.Equals(currentWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            // check the wordsToLowerCase array for the current word
            bool shouldLowerCaseThisWord = wordsToLowerCase.Any(stringToTest => stringToTest.Equals(currentWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            
            // add the current word to the output list
            if (shouldUpperCaseThisWord)
                outputWords.Add(currentWord.ToUpper());
            else if (shouldLowerCaseThisWord)
                outputWords.Add(currentWord.ToLower());
            else
                outputWords.Add(currentWord);
        }
        
        string finalOutput = String.Join(" ", outputWords);
        
        Console.WriteLine(finalOutput);
    }
}
```